# Linearly independent sets

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A and B be linearly independent subsets of a finite dimensional vector space.

I want to show that

if |A|>|B| then there exists an x in A s.t. B union {x} is linearly independent.

My proof is

' Let |A|=n and |B|=r.

Suppose B union {x} is linearly dependent for all x in A then span A is in span B.

Since |B|=r , vector space spanned by B has dimension at most r.

And vector space spanned by A has dimension at most r , since span A is in span B.

But then it is contradict to A is linearly independent , since |A|=n > r implies A is linearly dependent.

Therefore our assumption is false '

Is that right?

And, someone have another proof? I want to prove it by using linearly independent but dimension of vector space.

Comment: Do you have proofs of the facts about dimension you are quoting without using the result you want to prove here?

Comment: It is true *if you know that the dimension exists* and is well-defined. The result is not obvious without some theorem on dimension, or at least Steinitz exchange lemma.